# How to display last total for each month for running total?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make running totals in SQL Server by month for an entire year. While the code succeeds in creating the running totals, many observations are returned for each day of each month, as the data table is made up of millions of observations, with many taking place during the same days.

```
USE PIERS

SELECT
    VDATE,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('LOS ANGELES') 
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) WC_LA,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('LONG BEACH') 
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) WC_LB,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('SEATTLE', 'TACOMA') 
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) WC_NWSA,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('OAKLAND') 
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) WC_Oakland,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('ABERDEEN WA', 'ANACORTES', 'ANCHORAGE', 'ASTORIA', 'BENICIA', 'COOS BAY', 'DUTCH HBR', 'EL SEGUNDO', 'EVERETT', 'JUNEAU', 'KALAMA', 'KETCHIKAN', 'KODIAK', 'LONGVIEW', 'MARCUS HOOK', 'MONTEREY', 'NEWPORT OR', 'PITTSBURG', 'PORT ANGELES', 'PORT TOWNSEND', 'PORTLAND OR', 'PT HUENEME', 'REDWOOD CY', 'SAN DIEGO', 'SAN FRANCISCO', 'STOCKTON', 'VANCOUVER WA')  
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) WC_Other,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('NEW YORK') 
                then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_NYNJ,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('SAVANNAH')then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Savannah,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('NORFOLK') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Norfolk,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('CHARLESTON') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Charleston,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('BALTIMORE') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Baltimore,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('JACKSONVILLE') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Jacksonville,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('MIAMI') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Miami,
    SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('PT EVERGLADES') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Everglades
,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('PHILADELPHIA') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Philadelphia
,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in ('ALBANY', 'BELFAST', 'BOSTON', 'BRIDGEPORT', 'BRUNSWICK', 'CHESTER PA', 'EASTPORT', 'ERIE', 'FALL RVR', 'FERNANDNA BCH', 'FT PIERCE', 'GLOUCESTER CY', 'HOPEWELL', 'MARTINEZ', 'MOREHEAD CY', 'NEW BEDFORD', 'NEW HAVEN', 'NEW LONDON', 'NEWPORT', 'NEWPORT NEWS', 'PAULSBORO', 'PENNSAUKEN', 'PERTH AMBOY', 'PLYMOUTH', 'PORTLAND ME', 'PROVIDENCE', 'PT CANAVERAL', 'RICHMOND VA', 'ROCHESTER', 'SALEM NJ', 'SEARSPORT', 'W PALM BCH', 'WILMINGTON DE', 'WILMINGTON NC') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) EC_Other

,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('HOUSTON') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) GC_Houston
,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('NEW ORLEANS') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) GC_NO
,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('MOBILE') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) GC_Mobile
,SUM(case when CONFLAG IN ('1', 'C', 'Y') AND USPORT in('AVONDALE', 'BATON ROUGE', 'BEAUMONT', 'BROWNSVILLE', 'CORPUS CHRSTI', 'DESTREHAN', 'FREEPORT TX', 'GALVESTON', 'GRAMERCY', 'GULFPORT', 'LK CHARLES', 'MANATEE', 'MORGAN CY', 'ORANGE', 'PANAMA CY FL', 'PASCAGOULA', 'PENSACOLA', 'PORT ARTHUR', 'PT LAVACA', 'RICHMOND', 'S LOUISIANA', 'SABINE', 'TAMPA', 'TEXAS CITY') then TEUS end) over (order by VDATE rows unbounded preceding) GC_Other
FROM
dbo.PIERS_IMP_2018
```

The output currently looks like this.

```
VDATE   WC_LA   WC_LB   WC_NWSA WC_Oakland  WC_Other    EC_NYNJ EC_Savannah EC_Norfolk  EC_Charleston   EC_Baltimore    EC_Jacksonville EC_Miami    EC_Everglades   EC_Philadelphia EC_Other    GC_Houston  GC_NO   GC_Mobile   GC_Other
2018-01-27  325733.70   312893.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.45   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
2018-01-27  325733.70   312893.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.63   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
2018-01-27  325733.70   312893.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.81   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
2018-01-27  325733.70   312895.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.81   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
2018-01-28  325733.70   312895.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.99   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
...
```

As you can see, I get an output made up of millions of entries, each adding a tiny amount over the previous one. Instead of this, I would like to only display the cumulative totals by month. For example, Jan would the total by the end of January and Feb the total by the end of Feb, ect...This would look somewhat like this.

```
VDATE   WC_LA   WC_LB   WC_NWSA WC_Oakland  WC_Other    EC_NYNJ EC_Savannah EC_Norfolk  EC_Charleston   EC_Baltimore    EC_Jacksonville EC_Miami    EC_Everglades   EC_Philadelphia EC_Other    GC_Houston  GC_NO   GC_Mobile   GC_Other
2018-01  325733.70   312895.15   90954.71    61868.57    9187.17 246965.99   142550.78   82106.38    67751.38    38852.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
2018-02 325733.70   312895.15   90974.71    61870.57    9187.17 247038.92   142576.78   82118.88    67751.38    38859.59    18528.73    28260.92    26714.52    20625.43    42341.01    80724.51    7704.58 7376.37 14115.45
...
```

Could you please help out with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posting a broken query without some explanation, sample input, expected output will not help us help you.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for instructions on how to ask a good question. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find the types of information you need to post. As it sits right now this is not answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried editing the question in order to make it more clear.

Comment: What would really help is the table definition, some sample data, and the desired output from that sample data. We are not human sql engines that can just read a query and the current output and tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are not grouping the individual values into monthly totals before trying to cumulative sum up the months, which is why you are seeing a windowed total for each row of your source data.

You can group your totals using a CTE and then apply the running total from there:

```
declare @t table(d date,v int);
insert into @t values
 ('20190101',1)
,('20190102',3)
,('20190106',8)
,('20190108',4)
,('20190116',7)
,('20190102',9)
,('20190204',2)
,('20190207',9)
,('20190216',4)
,('20190220',6);

with m as
(
    select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,d),0) as m -- Date arithmetic to return the start of the month
            ,sum(v) as MonthlyTotal
    from @t
    group by dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,d),0)
)
select m
        ,sum(MonthlyTotal) over (order by m) as CumulativeTotal
from m
order by m;
```

## Output

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+
|            m            | CumulativeTotal |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |              32 |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 |              53 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
```